# GSON error with Cookie Persistence

Tags: android, cookies, kotlin, gson, kotlin-android-extensions

Currently working with an Android WebView and created a Kotlin class to handle Cookie Persistence. My error is occurring when setting the cookie. I am doing this process with GSON.

GSON is being loaded as a dependency with Gradle. It is also there at runtime.

The exact error I'm getting is:
[image: Possible fix per IDE]

Here is the code for this error:
[image: Code]

Per the GSON repository, this seems to work and the exact solution has been used before and is working. I am trying to understand what I am missing and how I can avoid the exact error "**None of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied**"

I also would like mention I tried writing the following to force the type to String and it was crashing the application at runtime.

[image]

Comment: try `gson.fromJSON(it.value as! String,DatedCookie::class)`

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh this seemed to solve it. Why is this exactly a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As mentioned here, use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50958770/gson-error-with-cookie-persistence?noredirect=1#comment88915210_50958770)

```
gson.fromJSON(it.value as! String,DatedCookie::class)
```

and as per the `fromJSON` error details with possible options, the best suitable one are

```
fromJSON(String!, Type) // here type is a class from gson lib which describe the type of conversion class, usually for complex types like list of POJO
fromJSON(String!, class) // the easy and more suitable one
```

so in the second option, the data is string and type is the class object of specific class